# Why does Wolfram say this sum equals 0?

Tags: real-analysis

Today I tried forming some $n$th-derivatives of certain functions involving trigonometric functions. And I formed an expression which holds my requirements for every derivative but not for the function itself:
\begin{align}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x\cos 2x)&=2^{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\biggl(\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2i^{n-1}}e^{2ix}+\frac{1}{2i^{n-1}}e^{-2ix}\biggr)\\& +  2^n\biggl(\frac{(-1)^{n}}{2i^{n}}e^{2ix}+\frac{1}{2i^{n}}e^{-2ix}\biggr)x 
\end{align}

This expression works perfectly fine for any $n \in \mathbb N$ but it also would work for $0$ if there weren't be the sum issue… that I cant really make it $0$. But than I figured.. well when I plug in $0$ everything works, but the sum goes for $k=1$ to $0$. So I asked Wolfram Alpha for fun if this sum is even defined. Wolfram surprisingly said:  $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{0} k = 0$.
I mean this looks more like undefined… and since Wolfram is not always to be trusted blindly, I wanted to ask you, why the sum equals zero for cases where the running index starts with a higher value than the upper bound of the summation.. I mean technically we don't sum anything, but it feels fishy… maybe someone has an explanation for this? Is it really defined, that if the running index starts with a higher value than the upper bound the sum always equals zero?

Comment: An empty sum is zero. An empty product is $1$.

Comment: okey, so I can use that in some cases for expressions? for example $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{-5} k = 0 $